# Sending orders from website to iOS app

Tags: ios, web

I try to explain as best as I can (and simplify a bit).

I have an iOS  app, asking the user 5 questions, 1 to 5 in this order. The questions are inside the app and the answers are then sent to a server via AF networking. It all works well.

I want to develop a web site with these same questions so somebody can choose which questions to be asked and in which order, for example 2, 5 and 3 only and in this specific order. Of course it will vary with each user. I then need to send this information back to the app and I want it after that to be Internet independent. I mean the questions and order are sent to the app (downloading or uploading) but then the user doesn't need Internet anymore to answer the questions (if there is no Internet to upload answers to server, the answers are automatically already saved in my app).

This surely must be possible but I don't see how exactly.

- Do I need to have the questions in my app (as now) or having them on the web site would be enough?
- How do I tell iOS to do something from my web site?
  ...

I am not after a precise tutorial, just some ideas thrown together to get me started, please.

Thanks a lot in advance for your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to have the questions in my app (as now) or having them on the web site would be enough?

It's a good idea to have them in the app, so if the app is first opened with no internet connection it will still be usable. Each time the app is opened it should try to get new data from the web service and update its internal store.

> How do I tell iOS to do something from my web site?

Generally, you don't. The app checks at appropriate times (like each launch).

---

Based on your comment below, the app should ask the user for his details and that is the trigger to connect to the server and obtain the active questions and order information. This can then be stored locally and the question interface can be presented to the user. Note, you could also return the number of days that should be recorded from the server...

On the next launch, you check for the existence of stored active questions and order information, and if you have some you go direct to the question interface.

The user should be presented with an option to upload the results (at the appropriate time), and you should have a setting somewhere to clear everything (just to remove the data, but also if the user needs to 'login' with different details for a new test session - so the app will check with the server again).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Wain. When I say "how do I tell iOS to so something from my web site?" I mean how do I tell: "use questions 5, 1 and 3 in that order?" I know how to program that in iOS, I will find out how to program that in the web site, but how does it come across to the app? It's not like just downloading data, do you know what I mean?

Comment: It is like downloading data. The app sends a request to the server with the user account / login details (upload request) and the server sends back the appropriate question info (download data)

Comment: I would add an "order" attribute in your response which will allow you to specify the order that you would like the questions to appear.

Comment: @ Wain. OK, I understand now. That's not what I had in mind, becasue I am then dependant on Internet. I wanted to download all the question at once with the order and then not need the web at all anymore. Is that possible?

Comment: @ Nick, that means I would need to have all questions inside the app and basically only transfer from the website the order then ?

Comment: You can just get the order, but you need a trigger, it doesn't need to be each time the app starts, but you need an internet connection at some point in time. You get to decide what the trigger is and how often it checks with the server (it could even be a manual request). Why is the server even required? If the user is choosing the questions for themselves then they can do it locally. Is it more like an admin and a set of users of that account?

Comment: @Wain. Sorry, it's because I try to make things simpler that I don't explain enough. It's a medical app. What I want to achieve is : The doctor chooses the questions on the web according to the patient profile. The patient gets the questions and the order on his app by downloading them. Then he has no contact with that website anymore and he answers the questions for 15 days everyday and uploads the answers to a server as norma. Hope it makes it clearer.

Comment: @user3227325, well, your app can ask a server for a list of questions (and even questions themselves), get this list (download the data as Wain said), save it, and then just work offline for 15 days then. You're gonna need an internet to get the 'orders' anyway, and 'orders' (a list of questions) is just a data, that you can download as anything else.

Comment: @ FreeNickname. So I download my questions and my order.  Currently the user clicks on start and the questions appear one after the other by pressing next.I don't understand how to integrate the downloaded questions and order to the app.May be it's so easy that I can't see it.